# Как использовать Sphinx в Yii2 + PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql, yii, sphinx

Не до конца понимаю, возможно ли использование Sphinxsearch в Yii2 в качестве поискового движка в связке с PostgreSQL? В экстеншене: [Yii2-sphinx](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-sphinx) говорится про MySQL, но про PgSQL ни слова. Сам экстеншен устанавливается, и конфиг вида:

```
'components' => [
    'sphinx' => [
        'class' => 'yii\sphinx\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=testdb',
        'username' => 'yii',
        'password' => '********',
    ],
]
```

ошибок не вызывает, даже при отсутствии Sphinx на сервере.
В связи с вышеизложенным возникает ряд вопросов:

1. Подходит ли данный экстеншен для использования его с PgSQL. Если да, где про это можно почитать, или посмотреть реальные примеры (Yii2 + PgSQL + Sphinx)?
2. Стоит ли использовать его, или лучше что-то другое, вроде: [pg-sphinx](https://github.com/andy128k/pg-sphinx)?
3. Стоит ли вообще его использовать, быть может есть решения быстрее и проще?

Стэк: Debian, Nginx, FPM, PHP7, Yii2, PgSQL

**UPD** Вопрос всё ещё актуален! :)

Comment: Мы в своем проекте используем полнотекстовый поиск на базе в 20 млн. записей. Полет нормальный. Так что может вам он и не нужен вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая фраза по ссылке [yii2-sphinx](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-sphinx) в блоке **Configuration**, говорит о том, что используется только протокол MySQL:

> This extension interacts with Sphinx search daemon using MySQL
>   protocol and SphinxQL query language.

По идее, Вы можете попробовать добавить `'pgsql' => 'yii\sphinx\Schema'`
 в массив `$schemaMap`, в файле Connection.php (в основной директории модуля), и, скорее всего простые запросы даже будут отрабатывать, но, как только будет более-менее сложный запрос, гарантирую, что Вы получите ошибку.

Лучшим вариантом будет использование расширения [pg-sphinx](https://github.com/andy128k/pg-sphinx) или похожее, если Вам действительно нужен Sphinx. В противном случае, попробуйте обычный полнотекстовый поиск, возможно, для ваших целей хватит и его.